# How do you overcome blindness?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am a fighter and in my game I managed to fuse with a dragon through a custom magic item but as I was role playing I had to fuse with my dragon I friended and he was blind so I became blind. How do I fix it.

The limits the DM set was that spells can only be from pathfinder core rulebook. My eyes are taken out of their eye sockets. Because they are missing, they don't count as broken, so the spell remove blindness/deafness doesn't work.

Comment: "Also my eyes are taken eye sockets and it is missing so it doesn't count as broken" - I don't understand this phrase at all. You seem to be saying your eyes are missing but then you say you don't count as broken?

Comment: @doppelgreener: Think OP means that missing eyes are explicitly excluded from the spell (which is in fact the case), unlike damaged eyes.

Comment: An important detail that may help focus answers is what level is your fighter, and what kind of resources can he get access to within the game.

Answer (score 11):

*Regenerate*, Cleric 7 (and Witch 7 and Shaman 7 and Druid 9 and Healing domain 7), should do the job for you just fine. You can probably hire a casting from an NPC, or buy a scroll, if you're not high enough a level for a team member to cast it.

Because it's an obviously helpful spell that several common classes can cast without needing to learn it specifically, it should be readily available anywhere you can hire spellcasting or buy scrolls of that level at all, barring fiat.

Answer (score 7):

The DM has somewhat invented the situation, and has not limited their own activity to the core rules. A "merge with a dragon" is very much a home-brewed situation. Now the DM may have in their own mind an exact solution, but also it is quite common to just roll with an idea because it seems cool.

I think this kind of character change is often a story-level one, and the DM may well have a mental image of how the merge has worked, and the sorts of things that may give your character back some sense. In addition, they may even have some sense of where things are going, or a specific plot point where the problem is resolved one way or another. However, they may also be following a pattern of throwing you a hard in-character problem and seeing where you take it.

As such, at the very least you will need to run ideas past your DM - by either trying them, or by talking through beforehand to get a sense of how the DM is thinking about the situation. You won't get a guaranteed win from any spell, short of a Wish to gain eyes or remove the merge (it would be a hard-nosed DM indeed that would stop Wish or Miracle curing such an affliction).

It is worth trying to understand how the dragon became blinded in the first place. If you know that it will give you clues as to what could work. The suggestion of *Regeneration* spell is a good one, if for example the dragon had eyes originally, but lost them somehow.

Off the top of my head, the resolution could be:

- Getting the merge reversed
- Fixing the dragon's eyes
- Somehow getting *your* eyes expressed in the merge
- Gaining magical Blind Sight, Echolocation or other sense to make up for the blindness (this might be a cool option, and the image of a [super-skilled warrior who cannot see is a common trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlindWeaponmaster)).

None of these are directly in the core rule book, they would come either from the DM's plot, or some combination of your suggestions for fixes and the DM's agreement on "that's how it works". It is worth trying some low-level spells such as Darkvision, simply because they are cheap to try, and will give you clues on how the DM is thinking. Don't worry too much if they don't work, in fact be prepared to find out that most simple things you can in character do not fix things.

Meanwhile a positive approach to play is to keep the character's blindness "on screen" so it is not forgotten (try not to nag or get depressed as a player about it). Try to have fun with it, at least from a story-telling perspective, and make it a key goal to pursue fixing it whenever possible - e.g. a stop in town should involve some research on what the options are.

Finally, if the change looks long term (no access to suitable magic, and DM not progressing your character's plot quickly to resolution), and you think that your character's new hybrid form is worth keeping then one simple thing you can do is gain Blind Fighting feat at the next available level for a feat. This may be worth it if the powers of your new hybrid form are fun to play, and if the DM has balanced the blindness in the merge somehow, this could even still be effective in combat (I'd hope at least you get a breath weapon, which usually doesn't need accurate aiming to score hits).

Comment: Strongly agree. Considering the problem itself isn't Core, limiting your options seems arbitrary. Talk to the DM out of game and ask where the plot is going.
p.s. Dragons have Blindsense 60', which explicitly isn't eye-based.

Answer (score 0):

The level 1 Spell [*Keen Senses*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/k/keen-senses) grants low light vision with a +2 competence bonus to Perception, but only lasts 1 minute/level.  The custom magic item creation system estimates a cost of 4000 gp for a magic item of continual Keen Senses.  Obviously, such an item should take the Eyes slot as its usual location.

The level 2 spell [*Darkvision*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkvision) will fix this but leave you colorblind, while its effects persist.  *Darkvision* can be made permanent, which avoids the need to deal with the custom magic item creation section.

Almost all form-altering spells (i.e. [*Polymorph*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph) and everything it links to, as well as [*Undead Anatomy*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/undead-anatomy-i), [*Angelic Aspect*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/angelic-aspect), [*Giant Form*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i), etc) can do this if you pick a form with low-light vision or darkvision.  If your GM has ruled that you lose your own gross physical qualities when you shift form (so you can't use *swallow whole* as a Tendriculos transformed into a halfling via *Alter Self*, for example) any form itself possessing vision would be sufficient, since your blindness is a gross physical quality.  A magic item will probably be the best choice to maintain the form indefinitely.

Eating the appropriate version of [*Demon Senses*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/demon-senses) will also fix this, but your eyes will grow in demonic.  +8 racial bonus, though.

*[Regenerate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/regenerate)*, at high levels or via scroll or NPC, will fix this and doesn't require maintenance.

Comment: Darkvision and low-light vision both appear to rely on existing eyes; LLV explicitly so. So I think the first two are likely to work poorly, and the third might be shaky.

Comment: Demon senses *chages* your eyes.  You need eyes to change, it doesn't grow them from nothing.

Comment: @TuggyNE I see no such rule for either.  Link?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer: Links are there in the spells you linked to. Relevant text: "[Darkvision] does not allow characters to see anything that they could not see otherwise" (i.e., other than negating the effects of non-magical darkness) and "Characters with low-light vision have eyes that are so sensitive to light that they can see twice as far as normal in dim light."

Comment: @TuggyNE Right, so low-light vision grants eyes explicitly.  The Darkvision quote is interesting however...

Comment: @thedarkwanderer: Reading that as anything other than "any eyes that they have are extra-sensitive to light" seems, to me, absolutely cheesy in the extreme.